# Oracle Apex Color DefaultAdd Row IG Button

Tags: oracle-apex

Is there a way to colour the Add Row/Edit buttons which are part of the Interactive Grid?

Basically change it to Hot button, what we can do with the page buttons.

Answer (score 1):

In your IG region > Attributes > Initialization Javascript Function it's possible to add config javascript for the IG. There are plenty of examples on the web of this, here is one example.

```
function (config)
{
    var $ = apex.jQuery,
        toolbarData = $.apex.interactiveGrid.copyDefaultToolbar();

    saveAction    = toolbarData.toolbarFind("save");
    // only icon, no label
    // saveAction.iconOnly = true;
    // icon location
    saveAction.iconBeforeLabel = true;
    // to use font apex icons, prefix with "fa"
    saveAction.icon ="icon-ig-save";
    // custom label
    saveAction.label = "Save it baby !";
    // hot or not
    saveAction.hot = false;
    config.toolbarData = toolbarData;

  return config;
}
```

[Official docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/23.1/aexjs/interactiveGrid.html#toolbarData) are also pretty good on this subject